# Dataflow giving error with query

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I've got an SSIS package with a dataflow in it to copy from one database to another.

Originally it was a copy from SQL2012 to SQL2012. This was no problem. Now I've had a requirement change and need to copy from SQL2008 R2 to SQL2012. The query now generates this error:

```
Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
```

The query causing it contains a parameter (type integer) that I am assigning in the OLEDB source:

```
SELECT MetricValues.MetricValue_RunId, MetricValues.MetricValue_SampleNumber, MetricValues.MetricValue_MetricId, MetricValues.MetricValue_Value
FROM MetricValues 
    INNER JOIN Runs ON MetricValues.MetricValue_RunId = Runs.Run_id 
    INNER JOIN STR_RequiredMetricList ON MetricValues.MetricValue_MetricId = STR_RequiredMetricList.id
WHERE (Runs.Run_endtime > DATEADD([day],  (?*-1), GETDATE()))
```

Its simply getting records that are less than [parameter] days old.

Is there something about copying from 2008 to 2012 that I need to know that could be causing this error?

Comment: What is  parameter (type integer) getting assigned with?

Comment: its getting assigned with the ssis parameter functionality in the OLE DB source object. When it was 2012 to 2012 the parameters list would come up fine, when doing 2008 R2 to 2012, clicking the Parameters button says that the Parameters can not be extracted from the SQL Command

Comment: A few things you could try - Does your query have any inline comments?  Check if the parameters come up in 2008 R2 after removing them. Does putting a space between ? and * help in getting the Parameters to  show up for 2008 R2?

Comment: Unfortunately no joy with those suggestions - I'm going to try creating a variable and setting the query up in that with a script object to see if that works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a solution, but as a workaround I created string package level variables and used a script object to populate them with the query and variables. I then referenced the query in the datasource.